# Weird behaviour of WPF Datagrid in .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

**Problem description:**
I have a small WPF window using Datagrid bound to an observable collection. When this window is launched in Windows OS having .net 4.5 then it works fine, but when I run in an OS where I have installed only .Net 4.0 (Example: Windows Server 2008R2) then this window crashes with the following exception.

[image: exception]

Or here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp33p.png

The same window works fine if I install .net 4.5 even though my application is based on .net 4.0 and I am not using any feature specific to .net 4.5.

It would be great if someone could explain why different behaviour ?

**Project can be found here:** http://1drv.ms/1k9Yolx
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to run your project at .Net4.5 and .Net 4.0 and I've not met any errors.

You've caught ArgumentOutOfRangeException and this Exception is not related with platform .Net4.0 and .Net 4.5. Moreover, there is ArgumentOutOfRangeException in both .Net4.0 and .Net 4.5.

The code `var t = Projects.ColumnFromDisplayIndex(2)` gets the DataGridColumn at the specified index. As you have 9 Columns(_name, ..., _path), 
you do nit catch any exception. However, if you set to 10 like this `Projects.ColumnFromDisplayIndex(10)`, you will catch an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`
as you are out of range(you have 9 columns, but you try to get no existed column ).

Comment: Thanks. The point here was that if my collection is empty in the OS having .net 4.5 also installed, still the columns were visible in the window but data grid was empty. But in .net 4.0 version the column itself does not get visible so the Columns property of the Datagrid is 0 whereas in .net 4.5 it will be 10.

Note: this behavior is visible only in an OS  if one of the two is installed not both.

Comment: @Sherry are you sure that the code is the same in both variants?

Comment: You've caught an exception and exception is not depended of installed platforms. It is just matter of what you want to take from DataGrid.

Comment: It seems the problem is related to this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cdc0fb6f-2335-42e2-98d7-4bd73ffffc8c/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-does-not-show-new-row-with-empty-collection?forum=wpf